# My portable SSD was 8 TB, and now it's 1 GB

Tags: ssd

My portable SSD was 8 TB, but now it's only 1 GB. The SSD was used for the TV, like a flash drive. I checked Disk Management, but there are no unallocated spaces.
It doesn't want to format.
Please say how I can fix it.

[image: Disk managment]

Comment: It's likely a result of the filesystem used [FAT] since IIRC FAT has a 2TB size limit _(69GB per 1TB of partition size is reserved for the filesystem itself, so a formatted 2TB partition would have 138GB reserved with 1.86TB remaining)_

Comment: 1.86TB is the limit of FAT. Don’t use FAT

Comment: If it's not going to be reconnected to the same TV, copy all data off it, format it to exFAT and _manually_ set the cluster [allocation unit] size to 4KB, because if you set it to anything higher, it will decrease the usable space by a power of 2 per 4KB _(e.g. a 32KB cluster size effectively has 8x less storage space than 4KB because a 4KB file will take 32KB of space and you will notice this)_

Comment: exFAT is a proprietary MS format. If you plan to use it on Windows (or Linux), NTFS has journaling (https://www.datto.com/blog/is-ntfs-journaled) and might be a better option.

Comment: If physical drive reports incorrect size then most likely you're dealing with a firmware issue. As long as a drive report to system it's 1 GB rather than in TB region, no amount of partitioning is going to help you. What you have is most likely a fake device.

Comment: I'd either like an English language screenshot or you providing a translation for all relevant info. English is only accepted language on SU AFAIK.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik exFat  WAS proprietary a few years ago. Microsoft has opened it up though. Anyone can now implement it and MacOS and Linux now support it out of the box. Problem is that he wants to use it in a TV. Most TV's can't deal with NTFS and many older TV's also not with exFat. Fat32 is the best you can do in that case, but that limits max file-size to 4 GB.

Comment: @Tonny, certainly, exFAT *can* be used on other OS, e.g. with *fuse*. However, exFAT is not recognized by many PC's *firmware*, as well as TV's. FAT32 is good for small drives, and would be the default for an unknown appliance, but it has no journaling and, as you state, has a 4 GB limit -- perhaps too small for a large video on that TV.

Answer (score 1):

Below Disk 1 you have the type of disk.
I can't read what is set on your SSD, but I can see that it is not basic.

It is either Dynamic Disk or MBR, I will guess dynamic as the writing are much longer.
The dynamic Disk is probably why you don't see all the space as it doesn't use a partition table.

Could you try to right click and convert disk to basic.
**Be informed that all the data on the disk will be erased.**

If you can't delete the partition and convert the disk to basic, you will have to resort to DiskPart.

With Diskpart you have to be very cautious as you may modify the wrong disk.
diskpart is a cli utility that help you interact with your disk, volume, and partition. It will allow you to perform action that diskmgmt.msc can't.

1. Open a cmd prompt
2. run diskpart to enter the diskpart utility. You will see the prompt is now like this:
   DISKPART>
3. run 'list disk' This will display the list of disk. With all the details as space. Ensure you see the whole size here.
4. run 'select disk x' replace x with the disk number (likely 2 in your case).
5. run 'list volume' to display the list of volume on the disk. You may see your lost space here.

Could you share what diskpart list disk and list volume retun?
This will give us more insight on what is going wrong with your ssd.

Comment: "_I would like to ensure what is the problem here before giving more Diskpart command that could break your computer._" that's just fearmongering - please explain

Comment: Diskpart is a powerful tool, but is quiet old and not relly intuitive to neophyte. When modifying disk format, parition, volume. If you selected the wrong diks, volume or partition, you can loose data or break you system parition. You won't break hardware, but you can easily kill your system.

Here we lack information to pin point what is the right solution to the problem. So naturally I can't advise him to run diskpart command to delete partition, create new parition or low level format is SSD.

Comment: Edit: rephrased the answer. But I want to ensure people are being cautious when using diskpart.

Comment: I've removed my downvote - cautious sure, but verification is easy to do and would be recommended over warnings - e.g. `lis dis`, `lis par` and once selected, `det dis` or `det par`, putting a comment above them in the code box: `::# Verify correct <disk||partition> is selected`

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely unlikely you have a fake device there. Many of the devices in TB country you can get from Amazon and such are fake drives with 'hacked' firmware that easily 'breaks'. They're often no more than USB flash dries or memory cards disguised as SSD. Some examples of these drives that were sold as portable SSD drives in the TB range:

[image]

[image]

Regardless of it being fake or not, even the firmware of legit SSDs can corrupt and if it does they typically start reporting an incorrect physical capacity.

Fact that Disk Management reports 1.8 GB physical capacity suggests this is not a logical issue but rather a firmware issue. No amount of disk-parting will resolve that.

[image]